# Using TLS on Freeswitch with CsipSimple on Android

Tags: android, ssl, freeswitch

Wondering if anyone has been able to get TLS and SRTP implemented with two CsipSimple clients and Freeswitch? Did you install client certs?  How did you get the two endpoints to communicate (receive incoming calls from each other)?

Currently, I can get two CSipSimple endpoints to register and signal using TLS but can't get incoming calls on either of them from either of them.